# Using MATLAB to create a 4D volume / contour plot

Tags: matlab, volume, 4d

I have the data set

```
1   1   1     0.07431
1   1   2     0.07176
1   1   3     0.06178
1   1   4     0.04691
...
27  27  44     0.07272
27  27  45     0.08129
```

where the first three columns are X, Y, Z points; which form a 27x27x45 grid of points. The last column is the value of the potential (V).

I want to plot this in a way which I can see where the potential is highest/lowest/what the data is doing - ideally something like the image below.

[image]

I'm pretty much an amateur at using MATLAB, but I think it might be the solution I'm looking for. I've installed the 'Sliceomatic' add-on, and attemped to run

```
sliceomatic(V,X,Y,Z)
```

but I get the error messages

```
Error using axes
While setting property 'YLim' of class 'Axes':
Value must be a 1x2 vector of numeric type in which the second element is larger than the first and may be Inf

Error in sliceomaticfigure (line 45)
      d.axmain = axes('units','normal','pos',[.2  .2 .6 .6],'box','on',...

Error in sliceomatic (line 200)
      d = sliceomaticfigure(d,xmesh,ymesh,zmesh);
```

Any other suggestions / help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because my grid of points is not equal along all axes (i.e. there are more z-points than x or y) - will this still work? I have tried using the `meshgrid` function, but perhaps I used it incorrectly.

Comment: The number of `x` and `y` points can be different, but the `z` points should be a matrix (n x m) where `n` is the length of `x` and `m` is the length of `y`. If `z` is an one dimensional array (1 x m) or (m x1) you can just plot a  line, not a surface (and in this case, the size of `x`, `y` and `z`  should be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a 4D surface plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001328/creating-a-4d-surface-plot)

Comment: OK - I think I understand what you mean, but how do I implement this into sliceomatic? Everything I attempt comes with an error message. i.e. when I use the code `[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(X,Y,Z,) , sliceomatic = (V, X, Y, Z)` - I get the message : `Error using issorted
Input must be a vector or 'rows' must be specified.

Error in sliceomaticfigure (line 30)
      if issorted(xmesh)~=1

Error in sliceomatic (line 200)
      d = sliceomaticfigure(d,xmesh,ymesh,zmesh);`